# Graphical SSH - SFTP Manager for ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ssh, 19.10, ftp, sftp

I was on windows for a long time.. and i installed ubuntu 19.10 now. i was using **Bitvise ssh** and **Mobaxterm** for manage my servers in windows...

In ubuntu i searched a lot but i couldn't find application like **Bitvise ssh** or **Mobaxterm**..

I just want an application that has these simple features :

- Sync automatically files on change (when i edit file) without asking for confirmation for override,etc...
- Bookmarks for saving count of servers with password (easy connection)
- has a simple terminal (SSH Connection)
- Not too old.

Just like **Bitvise ssh**

I know wine. If you want to suggest that to use bitvise ssh in linux i say its my last way.

I tried ubuntu default file manager as sftp client, and it needs confirmation at file change and override everytime. and takes too time to upload.

Comment: Have a look at this https://snapcraft.io/sftpclient

Comment: it's a web application and not so useful. Thanks for your suggestion.